# Getting "Invalid API call in the current context" error while writing data to excel using office.js from Task pane application

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

**Actual Issue:**

Getting error message "Invalid API call in the current context" from office.js
(API method: Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync)

**Issue scenarios:**

1) If a read/write operation is being performed on a namerange in Excel through Office.js, and User is trying to manually edit any sheet in the same excel
(in parallel), then Office.js operation fails with an error "Invalid API call in the current context".

2) If a read/write operation is being performed on a namerange in Excel through Office.js, and User is trying to manually edit any sheet in the another excel
sheet (in parallel), then Office.js operation fails with an error "Invalid API call in the current context".

**Error message from Office JS:** Invalid API call in the current context.

[View the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0eN1.png)

Comment: When you say "edit any sheet in the another excel sheet", do you mean "edit any sheet in the another excel workbook"?

Comment: yes Rick Kirkham.